# Solving 3D system of equations with two algebraic eqs. and one parametric?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I'm trying to find a way to compute all solutions to system of three equations. Two of them are usuall algebraic equations, and third one is a parametric equation. Is there any way, to for example combine them in Solve[] command?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Lets get it down to 2D situation: Let's say I have cirlce of radius 2 (x^2+y^2=2^2), and a line y=x+1. I can easily use command Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 4, y == x + 1}, {x, y}] and find the two solutions. But for reasons, I'd like to have circle in parametric form {{cos(t),sin(t)},{t,0,2pi}}, and receive t values for which it is fulfilled.

Comment: Really need an example to work with...

Comment: Lets get it to down to 2D situation:

Let's say I have cirlce of radius 2 (x^2+y^2=2^2), and a line y=x+1. I can easily use command Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 4, y == x + 1}, {x, y}] and find the two solutions.

But for reasons, I'd like to have circle in parametric form {{cos(t),sin(t)},{t,0,2pi}}, and receive t values for which it is fulfilled.

Comment: edit your question to include the example, to get more responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, based on yours above. You have a line and a circle of variable radius.

```
line = y==x + 1

circle = {x == rr Cos[t], y == rr Sin[t]}
```

Use `Reduce[ ]` and we get a set of possible solutions with parameter `rr`, and values for which it holds true.

```
Reduce[Flatten@{line, circle}, {x, y, t}]

C[1] ∈ Integers &&

(rr == 1 && ((
  x == 0 && 
  y == 1 &&  
  t == π/2 + 2 π C[1]) ||

(x == -1 && 
 y == 0 &&   
 t == π + 2 π C[1]))) ||

(-1 + rr !=  0 && 
 ((rr (-1 + 2 rr + Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) != 0 && 
 x == 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) && 
 y == 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) && 
 t == 2 ArcTan[(-rr - Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2])/(-1 + rr)] + 2 π C[1]) ||

(rr (-1 + 2 rr - Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) != 0 && 
 x == 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) && 
 y == 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2]) && 
 t == 2 ArcTan[(-rr + Sqrt[-1 + 2 rr^2])/(-1 + rr)] + 2 π C[1])
```